# How I can delete the first column in even rows?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I've got the next file:

```
Ca 1
 1 -5.338208778 -0.000000000 -15.624910016
Ca 2
 2 -2.262452484 -2.494999886 -12.589102506
Ca 3
 3 -8.095800400 -2.494999886 5.624757806
Ca 4
 4 -7.282658184 -0.000000000 -9.553623225
Ca 5
 5 -4.206901709 -2.494999886 -6.517815410
Ca 6
 6 -1.131307069 0.000000000 -3.482008572
Ca 7
 7 -6.151351054 -2.494999886 -0.446529291
Ca 8
 8 -3.075756535 0.000000000 2.589278525
.. .. .. ... .. .. ..
```

I would like to delete the first field of the even rows (the number). I tried with`awk` but I didn't find the solution...

Many thanks in advance.
Git.

EDIT

The output should be like:

```
Ca 1
   -5.338208778 -0.000000000 -15.624910016
Ca 2
   -2.262452484 -2.494999886 -12.589102506
Ca 3
   -8.095800400 -2.494999886 5.624757806
Ca 4
   -7.282658184 -0.000000000 -9.553623225
Ca 5
   -4.206901709 -2.494999886 -6.517815410
Ca 6
   -1.131307069 0.000000000 -3.482008572
Ca 7
   -6.151351054 -2.494999886 -0.446529291
Ca 8
   -3.075756535 0.000000000 2.589278525
.. .. .. ... .. .. ..
```

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Yeah! Edit to show you the desired output. Thanks

Comment: I think is not duplicate becose nobody dealing with the even rows: the answer proposed just delete the first field of whole rows not even rows. please, help.

Comment: I got it finally the solution `awk 'NR%2==0 {print $1="", $2, $3, $4} NR%2==1 {print $1, $2}' file` if these serve to others.